# Email Account List not Showing Up in Folder Pane

Tags: thunderbird

Usually all the accounts that was added to Thunderbird will show up on the folder pane, each having their own inbox, drafts, sent, and trash folder.

However for some reason on the computer my friend is using only Local Folder shows up despite having 3 accounts added to it.

How do I make it so that it shows each email accounts (like I described in paragraph one)?

His Thunderbird is version 60.